# Wait for process start with ProcessBuilder in Java

Tags: java, process, exec, processbuilder

I'm using Processbuilder in Java to start an external jar application :

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", "app.jar");
Process p = pb.start();
p.waitFor();
```

But the waitfor method wait for app ending. I just want to wait the opening of the app. It's running on windows and it take too long to launch app.

Is there a way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you want to wait till the app is started. I am not sure if there is something for help in process but optionally you can code to check if the port is open on which your app is going to run. Once the app is up the port will become open.

Comment: It's a good idea, I find the reason why app take too long to open, it was analysed by wndowsDefender before it be open. Maybe there is a way to open app or test one time in order to windowsDefender analyse it and after open the app for the user.